# Uniform continuity with integral being finite

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, uniform-continuity

Let $f$ be a real valued uniformly continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ that is lebesgue integrable.

Show that $\lim_{|x|\rightarrow \infty}f(x)=0$.

Suppose that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)dx=M<\infty$$

Suppose that  $\lim_{|x|\rightarrow \infty}f(x)=L\neq 0$ i.e., given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $R$ such that for all $|x|>R$ we have $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ i.e., $-\epsilon+L<f(x)<\epsilon+L$ for all $x:|x|>R$

We then have $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)dx=
\int_{-\infty}^{-R}f(x)dx+\int_{-R}^R f(x)dx+\int_R^{\infty}f(x)dx$$
$$\geq (-\epsilon+L)(\mu(-\infty,R)+\mu(R,\infty))+2RL$$

Where $L$ is the maximum of $f(x)$ on $[-R,R]$..

I some how plan to manipulate  $(-\epsilon+L)(\mu(-\infty,R)+\mu(R,\infty))+2RL$ to be strictly greater than $M$ then by getting a contradiction.

could not proceed beyond this.

Have not yet used uniform continuity as of now.

Comment: You cannot use the assumption that there is some nonzero limit, because the negation of "the limit is zero" is "the limit exists and is nonzero or the limit does not exist". That second scenario is really where the question is interesting, because there are continuous, Lebesgue integrable functions which have no limit at infinity (but they aren't uniformly continuous).

Comment: Instead, assuming that the limit isn't zero amounts to assuming that there is a divergent sequence $x_n$ with $|f(x_n)|>\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$. Take small intervals around these points and use uniform continuity to conclude that $\int |f| dx = +\infty$.

Comment: I understand your first comment... Second comment is a bit confusing... @Ian

Comment: You need to write out the negation of "the limit is zero". This basically says that there is some $\epsilon$ such that there are arbitrarily large $x$ with $|f(x)|>\epsilon$. You can use this to get a sequence like I described.

Comment: Ok... By $\lim_{|x|\rightarrow \infty}f(x)=0$ we mean, given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $R>0$ such that for all $x$ with $|x|>R$ we have $|f(x)|<\epsilon$.. Negation of this is that there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that given $R>0$ there exists $x$ with $|x|>R$ we have $|f(x)|>\epsilon$.. in particular, for each $n$ there exists $x_n$ such that $|x_n|>n$ and $|f(x_n)|>\epsilon$.. so, we have a divergent sequence as you have said in second comment.. @Ian

Comment: @Ian : As $f$ is uniformly continuous, for this $\epsilon$,  there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ for all $x,y$ with $|x-y|<\delta$...

Comment: Consider $(x_n-\delta/2,x_n+\delta/2)$ nbds around each $x_n$.. For $a\in (x_n-\delta/2,x_n+\delta/2)$ we have $|f(a)-f(x_n)|<\epsilon$ i.e., $-\epsilon+f(x_n)<f(a)<\epsilon+f(x_n)$.. We have $|f(x_n)|>\epsilon$ for all $n$ we can say that $|f(x_n)|=\epsilon+r_n$ for some $r_n>0$... i.e., we may have $f(x_n)=-\epsilon-e_n$ or $\epsilon+r_n$.. In any case we have $|f(a)|>r_n$... So, on each interval, minimum value of $f$ is strictly positive.... We then have $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f|dx\geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{(x_n-\delta/2,x_n+\delta/2)}|f(a)|dx\geq \delta\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r_n$$...

Comment: Now, i have two question.. first one is that those intervals $(x_n-\delta/2,x_n+\delta/2)$ may not be disjoint.. Even if they are, there is a second difficulty, the divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r_n$.. It can still be convergent...

Comment: So you actually don't want to just get any old divergent sequence. You want to get a divergent sequence where the points all have some minimum spacing apart. So get your $\epsilon$ from the non-convergence, then get your $\delta$ from uniform continuity with that $\epsilon$. If your $\delta$ was at least $1$, make it $1/2$ instead for purposes of constructing intervals. Then use the non-convergence to get a sequence $x_n$ with $|f(x_n)|>\epsilon$ and $x_{n+1} \geq x_n+1$. You can do that if you look carefully at the definition of the statement (and accept some choice axiom or another).

Comment: @Ian : I have written some answer.. See if that is fine... I have to get rid of this assumption anyways

Comment: I saw your answer, it has the problem I mentioned: just assuming $x_n>n$ is not enough, because of the possibility of overlap. You need to assume $x_{n+1}-x_n$ is bigger than some fixed amount. But you can still do that inductively: once you know what $x_n$ is, use the non-convergence statement to find $x_{n+1} \geq x_n+1$, and iterate.

Answer (score 0):

By $\lim_{|x|\rightarrow \infty}f(x)=0$ we mean :

> given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $R>0$ such that for all $x$ with $|x|>R$ we have $|f(x)|<ϵ$.

Negation of this is that :

> there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that given $R>0$ there exists $x$ with $|x|>R$ we have $|f(x)|>\epsilon$..

In particular, for each $n$ there exists $x_n$ such that $|x_n|>n$ and $|f(x_n)|>\epsilon$.

As $f$ is uniformly continuous :

> given $\epsilon$ as above there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon/2$

We have $|f(x_n)|>\epsilon/2$. Let $a\in(x_n-\delta/2,x_n+\delta/2)$. Suppose $|f(a)|\leq \epsilon/2$ then we have
$$|f(x_n)|\leq |f(x_n)-f(a)|+|f(a)|<\epsilon/2+\epsilon/2=\epsilon.$$

This says that $|f(a)|>\epsilon/2$ for all $a\in(x_n-\delta/2,x_n+\delta/2)$..

We can choose $\delta'<\min\{1,\delta\}$ and put $\delta'=\delta$, abuse of notation.. This is to make sure that the intervals $(x_n-\delta/2,x_n+\delta/2)$ are disjoint.. In this case, we do have $(x_n-\delta/2,x_n+\delta/2)\subset(n,n+1)$.. I realize that this is where we use $|x_n>n|$... I am explicitly assuming $x_n\in (n,n+1)$.. no idea how to get rid of this assumption..

As those intervals are disjoint, we now have 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|dx\geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{x_n-\delta/2}^{x_n+\delta/2}|f(x)|dx\geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\epsilon/2\delta=\infty.$$

Only gap is the assumption that $x_n\in (n,n+1)$..